# EKEvent <!ExceptionDate!> vs RID

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekevent, ekeventkit

I have iOS application(written on objective c) which works with events from the calendar. 
Something strange that I saw is on change of recurrent meeting is that in the most of the cases the calendarItemExternalIdentifier field was changed and there is /RID=XXXXXXX part is added but in some of the cases I receive same calendarItemExternalIdentifier with 20161205 added at the end.

For example I have external identifiers like this:

```
oiok2qp12o6k3d2ru34v885njo@google.com
```

And on change  I can receive this:

```
oiok2qp12o6k3d2ru34v885njo@google.com/RID=505299600
```

or this:

```
oiok2qp12o6k3d2ru34v885njo@google.com<!ExceptionDate!>20161205
```

Why we have this and what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I figured out (while on search for an answer for this, too)<  the difference relies on which calendar type you are using.

**Exchange Calendar** events use **/RID=**, where the Timestamp is the time interval since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 to the new Date.

while

**Local Calendar** (and I think CalDAV Calendars - I'll check this later) use

Comment: Yes the difference is in the type of the calendars, thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Have you figured out something about other calendar types yet?

Comment: No, just start using mostly the first part of the external id where in the example is oiok2qp12o6k3d2ru34v885njo@google.com.